# Overlay an Eigenvector with imaginary components on a ParametricPlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I have several 1-by-3 Eigenvectors with imaginary components that I would like to overlay on a ParametricPlot3D using Show. For example, I used the Eigenvectors command which outputs:

```
 {{a,b,c},{d,e,f},{g,h,i}}
```

where a-c are real numbers and d-i are real and imaginary numbers. I wish to plot only {d,e,f} at the point (3,4,5) on a figure along with a curve produced by ParametricPlot3D. (a-i are real and imaginary numbers).

I am able to use:

```
Graphics3D[Arrow[{{3, 4, 5}, #}] & /@ {{3, 4, 5} + {a,b,c} }];
```

for the Eigenvector with only real values.

To reiterate, I have an Eigenvector, say {0.5+i,0.5-i,.5}, that I want to place at the point (3,4,5) and display that with another curve on a 3D plot (Preferably by using Show[] to display the ParametricPlot3D curve and the Eigenvector on the same figure).

I am new here and BAD at Mathematica, so answers for morons are appreciated!

Comment: What you want is simply not possible: One would need a six-dimensional plotting space to display a complex 3-vector.